# In Apple Numbers what formula can calculate the amount of days in a certain month across 2 dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, iwork-numbers

I copied and pasted an identical question regarding Excel. I tried following the solution in Numbers but I always get this error message "the operator "*" needs a number but it found 01/01/2020".

This is the formula I copied:

```
=NOT(OR(D$1>$B2,EOMONTH(D$1,0)<$A2))*(MIN(EOMONTH(D$1,0)+1,$B2)-MAX(D$1,$A2))
```

I basically need to know how many nights in a specific month were booked. If a guest arrived on Dec 27 and left on Jan 6 what can I do to have columns that say "December: 4", "January: 6" etc?

Thank you very much

Comment: Could you please share some sample data with us. Also in which cell you have applied the shown formula !!

Comment: What does your posted formula, or the question for that matter, have to do with Excel?

Answer (score 0):

*Addressing your issue, "I basically need to know how many nights in a specific month were booked,,".*

- If you want to count Days/Nights between two Dates then, you have to use DATE TIME STAMP format, compromise Date & Time both along with AM/PM.

[image]

**:Formula used are:**

- Q13= `=ROUND(P12,0)-INT(O12)`
- Q14= `=ROUND(P12+1/24,0)-INT(O12)`
- R13= `=DAYS(P12,O12)`

*You may also use DATEDIF to get DAYS.*

---

**One more method I would like to show:**

- Shows which Dates have been occupied between two dates.

[image]

- Formula in cell T12, fill Right:

`=IF(AND($O$12<T$11,$P12>T$11),1,0)`

**N.B.**

*Adjust Start & End Dates, as well cell references in the formula as needed.*